# Подключение шрифтов в scss через mixin

Tags: css, scss

Здравствуйте почему у меня не работает вот этот mixin в(scss) 
вот это mixin что я делаю не так

```
@mixin font-face($font-family, $file-path, $weight: normal, $style: normal, $asset-pipeline: false ) {
@font-face {
    font-family: $font-family;
    font-weight: $weight;
    font-style: $style;
}

@if $asset-pipeline == true  {
    src: font-url('#{$file-path}.eot');
    src: font-url('#{$file-path}.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), font-url('#{$file-path}.woff') format('woff'), font-url('#{$file-path}.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@else {
    src: url('#{$file-path}.eot');
    src: url('#{$file-path}.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('#{$file-path}.woff') format('woff'), url('#{$file-path}.ttf') format('truetype');

     } 
  }
```

вот это include (scss)

```
@include font-face("firaSans", "../fonts/FiraSansRegular/FiraSansRegular");
```

вот выкидывает gulp такую ошибку
**

> **Error: no mixin named font-face
>          Backtrace:
>           dev/scss/_misc/_fonts.scss:1
>           on line 1 of dev/scss/_misc/_fonts.scss
>
> > > @include font-face("firaSans", "../fonts/FiraSansRegular/FiraSansRegular");    ---------^**

**

Answer (score 2):

Отредактируйте Ваш `mixin` таким образом и все заработает:

```
@mixin font-face($font-family, $file-path, $weight: normal, $style: normal) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: $font-family;
        font-weight: $weight;
        font-style: $style;
        src: url('#{$file-path}.eot');
        src: url('#{$file-path}.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('#{$file-path}.woff') format('woff'), url('#{$file-path}.ttf') format('truetype');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

mixin используется для добавления стилей элементу, а @font-face это декларация шрифта в проекте и лежит в корневой вложенности.

Answer (score 1):

Делаете, например, так.
В отдельном файле создаете шрифты:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "RobotoRegular";
  src : url("../fonts/RobotoRegular/RobotoRegular.ttf");
}
```

Затем подключаете к основному файлу:

```
@import "app/sass/fonts.sass";
```

И потом присваиваете:

```
h1 {
  font: 14px RobotoRegular;
  color: black;
}
```